# Tests for django app produces template not found error for "render_to_string" when executed via Fabric

Tags: django, unit-testing, fabric

When I run tests on my remote server using fabric, I get an error saying:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html
```

I am trying to render the template as a string using "render_to_string()"
If I login to the server and run tests manually (python manage.py test app), it is working properly. This error occurs while running through fabric.

Here is my fabric code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import local
import os
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['server.com']
production_project_path = '/path/to/production/app/'

def run_remote_test():
    run("python %s/manage.py test app"%production_project_path)
```

Did I miss something?
Note: I am not using virtual environment

Comment: did you try specifying 'pty=False' to the 'run' command?

Comment: Other thing I'm thinking would be to rewrite this as 'with cd(production_project_path): run("python manage.py test app")

Comment: @favoretti It worked!!! ((with cd(production_project_path): run("python manage.py test app"))) Thank you

Comment: Great, made an answer out of it, rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then let's make this official. ;)

In this case, the problem was the fact that manage.py expects to be ran from the project directory, so rewriting the abovestanding as:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import local
import os
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['server.com']
production_project_path = '/path/to/production/app/'

def run_remote_test():
    with cd(production_project_path):
        run("python manage.py test app")
```

has fixed the issue.